# Wordpress Dynamic Meta Box

Tags: custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, meta-boxes

I am trying to create a custom meta box that lets you add rows dynamically. Following code snippet works fine and and saves data in my edit page section. However, I can't get it to display the data on the actual page.

```
    // –––Dynamic Custom Box

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'dynamic_sectionid',
    __( 'My Tracks', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'dynamic_inner_custom_box',
    'page');
}

/* Prints the box content */
function dynamic_inner_custom_box() {
global $post;
// Use nonce for verification
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamicMeta_noncename' );
?>
<div id="meta_inner">
<?php

//get the saved meta as an array
$songs = get_post_meta($post->ID,'songs',true);

$c = 0;
   if(is_array($songs)){
    foreach( $songs as $track ) {
        if ( isset( $track['title'] ) || isset( $track['track'] ) ) {
            printf( '<p>Song Title <input type="text" name="songs[%1$s][title]" value="%2$s" /> -- Track number : <input type="text" name="songs[%1$s][track]" value="%3$s" /><span class="remove">%4$s</span></p>', $c, $track['title'], $track['track'], __( 'Remove Track' ) );
            $c = $c +1;
        }
      }
    }
 ?>
   <span id="here"></span>
   <span class="add"><?php _e('Add Tracks'); ?></span>
   <script>
      var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
      $(".add").click(function() {
         count = count + 1;

         $('#here').append('<p> Song Title <input type="text" name="songs['+count+'][title]" value="" /> -- Track number : <input type="text" name="songs['+count+'][track]" value="" /><span class="remove">Remove Track</span></p>' );
        return false;
    });
    $(".remove").live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
</div><?php
  }
   /* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
   function dynamic_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
   // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
     return;

 // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
 // because save_post can be triggered at other times
 if ( !isset( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'] ) )
     return;

 if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
     return;

 // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

 $songs = $_POST['songs'];

 update_post_meta($post_id,'songs',$songs);
 }

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_songs_meta' );
```

As you can see, 'page' is referring to page where I want to post to. Now when I loop for the results on the page template nothing shows up.

```
 <?php            
            $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page', 
);  
$repeat_loop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $repeat_loop->have_posts() ) :while ( $repeat_loop->have_posts() ) : $repeat_loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'songs', true ); ?>
        <p style="color: #111111 !important;"><?php echo $meta['title']; ?><? php echo $meta['track']; ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Since my output is an array, I need to loop through it like so:

```
    <?php for( $i= 0 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ ) echo '<p>' .$meta[$i]['title']. '</p>';?>
```